# CSS width mix fixed and % -- auto fill max space --

Tags: css

I have a wrap  that contains a side bar and a content area, my side bar is fixed to 240px but the content area I want to be max width of the remainder of the window.

However I can't achieve this. I have attempted `width: 100%` which stretches over the entire window. I tried auto which doesn't work. I don't know what else I can try.

Here is my code:

```
/*** Content ***/
.con_wrap{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.cont{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.left_side{
    background: #22282b;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sidebar you should have `float: left` and for the content that you want to the right of your sidebar you should define `overflow: hidden`.

An easy example to follow is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dkGbd/

The way this works is by declaring a Block formatting context on the element to the right with the `overflow` property.

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, inline-blocks, table-cells, table-captions, and elements with '**overflow**' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

Comment: perfect, can you explain to me the logic why this worked? I though overflow hidden was only for content with in the wrap? why does it affect width such way? Thanks

Comment: @theStudent pssst. It's been 3 minutes